# Detect inappropriate variable usage within preprocessor #if

Tags: c++, constexpr, preprocessor, if-constexpr

Consider the following arbitrary yet oversimplified code:

```
#define CONST_BAR 2

int foo(int x)
{
#if CONST_BAR > 0
    return x * CONST_BAR;
#else
    return x;
#endif
}
```

Suppose that we have many code blocks throughout multiple files that reference CONST_BAR in similar preprocessor directives. I'd like to refactor CONST_BAR to be a `constexpr int` instead. The problem is that if I fail to succeed in spotting all preprocessor directives that reference `CONST_BAR` in a similar manner, my code will suddenly be wrong in all places:

```
constexpr int CONST_BAR = 2;

int foo(int x)
{
#if CONST_BAR > 0
    return x * CONST_BAR;
#else
    return x;
#endif
}
```

The problem is that none of the compilers I'm using (MSVC, clang) emit an error or a warning that `#if CONST_BAR > 0` is obviously incorrectly used, and the preprocessor directive will actually evaluate as false, changing the behavior of my function when that wasn't my intention. I really intended the following:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    if constexpr (CONST_BAR > 0)
    {
        return x * CONST_BAR;
    }
    return x;
}
```

How do I make a compiler spot this as an error so I can correct it?

Comment: First, make it `#define CONST_BAR !`. That will trigger an error everywhere `#if CONST_BAR > 0` appears. Fix those errors, then change the macro to a variable.

Comment: Reasonable, but I hope there's a better way. IRL I've changed 30 or so #defines similarly. I'd rather not go one by one, and also I'd imagine that correct usage will also not compile either.

Comment: Re: correct usage. Temporarily name the variable `CONST_BAR_X` or something. Do the bad macro trick to find bad macro usage and replace with good variable usage. Then remove the macro, rename the variable, and update usage of the variable to the new name. Anyplace you forget to update would trigger a compiler error.

Comment: Actually so far the easiest thing I've found is using regex in "find in files", and include all the former macros in the expression
#.+(CONST_BAR|CONST_BAR_2|CONST_BAR_3...etc)

Comment: You can use ```#ifdef CONST_BAR``` to check if the macro exists or not before using the ```#if``` to avoid the wrong evaluation of ```#if```

Comment: Of course, but I first would need to find all the usages of it, which is exactly my problem in the first place. It sure would be nice if a compiler would emit an error or at least a warning on direct usage within an #if preprocessor.